# Constructing GET url to retrieve JSON from JS button click function

Tags: javascript, python, api, web-scraping, get

I am trying to scrape this page using requests and BeautifulSoup in Python but the page is in Javascript so I am including both tags for the question. The page is

https://untappd.com/v/southern-cross-kitchen/469603

and others like it, but it has a 'Show More' button. I want to avoid using a headless browser so I went snooping around for the JavaScript behind this to see if I can find a url, get or post request.

After some inspection, this is the button's code:

```
<a class="yellow button more show-more-section track-click" data-href=":moremenu" data-menu-id="78074484" data-section-id="286735920" data-track="venue" data-venue-id="469603" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

and it is controlled and redirected by this function:

```
$(document).on("click", ".show-more-menu-section", (function() {
        var e = $(this);
        $(e).hide();
        var t = $(this).attr("data-venue-id"),
            a = $(this).attr("data-menu-id"),
            n = $(".section-area .menu-section").length;
        return $(".section-loading").addClass("active"), $.ajax({
            url: "/venue/more_menu_section/" + t + "/" + n,
            type: "GET",
            data: "menu_id=" + a,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(t) {
                $(".section-loading").removeClass("active"), $(e).show(), $.notifyBar({
                    html: "Hmm. Something went wrong. Please try again!",
                    delay: 2e3,
                    animationSpeed: "normal"
                })
            },
            success: function(t) {
                $(".section-loading").removeClass("active"), "" == t.view ? $(e).hide() : (trackMenuView("viewMoreMenuSection"), t.count >= 15 ? ($(e).show(), $(".section-area").append(t.view)) : $(".section-area").append(t.view), handleNew())
            }
        })
```

which is contained in https://assets.untappd.com/assets/v3/js/venue/venue.menu.min.js?v=2.7.10

So for the required values in the function, `t`, `a` and `n` are:

```
t = 469603
n = 78074484
a = 1
```

I am now trying to construct the url using this `url` part of the function which is:

```
url: "/venue/more_menu_section/" + t + "/" + n
```

Using `https://www.untappd.com` as my base url, I have tried the following urls with no luck:

`/venue/more_menu_section/469603/1?data=%7B%22menu_id%22%3A%2278074484%22%7D`

`/venue/more_menu_section/469603/1?data%3D%7B%22menu_id%22%3A78074484%7D`

`/venue/more_menu_section/469603/1?data=%7B%22menu_id%22%3A78074484%7D`

`/venue/more_menu_section/469603/1?data={"menu_id":78074484}`

As a result, I have not been able to programmatically retrieve the data. I really would want to avoid using webdrivers and headless browsers to simulate clicks so I am guessing this should be possible with a GET request. Creating that url is proving a challenge.

How can I do create the right url to fetch?

Answer (score 0):

> So for the required values in the function, `t`, `a` and `n` are:
>
> ```py
> t = 469603 
> n = 78074484 
> a = 1
> ```

I think you mixed up the `n` and `a` values, but how do you get your `n`? In the JS code, it counts the number of elements that can be css-selected with `.section-area .menu-section` [basically, the number of menu sections displayed] - is it really just 1?

And you don't need to add `data=..` in your url - the key-value pairs *inside* `data` should be joined by ampersand in the query like `?key1=value1&key2=value2...` [URL encoded ofc], so just `?menu_id={a}` in this case.

---

However, getting the URL right isn't enough - are you setting the right headers? If I look at the network logs, you need to set `'accept': 'application/json'` and `'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'` to get the JSON response [with html in `$.value`], and you should set some [user agent](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-fake-and-rotate-user-agents-using-python-3/) [like `'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'`] to not get blocked.

---

But also, the URL I noticed in the network logs (for the [Southern Cross Kitchen page](https://untappd.com/v/southern-cross-kitchen/469603) to be specific) seems to be more in the **`/venue/more_menu/{venue_id}/{n}?section_id={section_id}`** format - I got an empty `$.value` with both

- the link that would be formed from your JS+HTML snippets (*`/venue/more_menu_section/469603/1?menu_id=78074484`*), as well as
- the `/more_menu/` link containing the sectionId in your html snippet (*`/venue/more_menu_section/469603/1?section_id=286735920`*), but

I got a [html string with 3 more items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGe6e.png) in `jData['value']` with

```py
headers = {
  'accept': 'application/json', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}
mmUrl = 'https://untappd.com/venue/more_menu/469603/15?section_id=287454773'
response = requests.get(mmUrl, headers=headers)
jData = response.json()
```

(`mmUrl` copied from network logs just now - maybe the sectionId changes?)

---

##### Complete Example

I've wrapped it in a function (`scrape_untappd_menu`) because I find it more convenient, especially in terms of error-handling.

<sub>**(If you try to run this, don't forget to include [`selectForList`](https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u).)**</sub>

```py
# def extract_..., selectForList ## PASTE FROM https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u

## just for returning and printing a message with one statement ##
def vRet(toPrint, toReturn=[]):
    print(toPrint)
    return toReturn

def scrape_untappd_menu(umLink, includeVenue=False):
    rootUrl,addSlash = 'https://untappd.com','' if umLink[:1]=='/' else '/'
    if not umLink.startswith(rootUrl):umLink=f'{rootUrl}{addSlash}{umLink}'
    selRef = {
      'name': 'div.beer-details>h5>a',
      'description': 'div.beer-details>h5>em',
      'rating': ('div[data-rating]', 'data-rating'),
      'label': 'div.beer-label',
      'label_updated':('div.beer-label>span[data-update-at]','data-update-at'),
      'about': 'div.beer-details>h6>span',
      'link': ('a[data-href=":beer"][href]', 'href'),
      'brewery': 'a[data-href=":brewery"]',
      'brewery_link': ('a[data-href=":brewery"][href]', 'href'),
      'log_src': ('a[data-href=":beer"]>img[src]', 'src')
    }

    ## fetch and parse page html ##
    pgResp = requests.get(umLink, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    try: pgResp.raise_for_status() 
    except Exception as e: return vRet(f'failed2scrape:{type(e)} - {e}')
    pgSoup = BeautifulSoup(pgResp.content)

    ## get some venue name and id ##
    vName, vn_h2, venuId = selectForList(pgSoup, [
        'div.venue-name>h1', 'div.venue-name>h2', 
        ('*[data-venue-id]', 'data-venue-id')])
    if not vName: vName =  umLink.split('/v/', 1)[-1].replace('-', ' ')
    if vn_h2: vName += f' [{vn_h2}]'
    if not venuId: print(f"could not find '*[data-venue-id]'") 
    
    ## get menu items from page ##
    mSel = 'ul.menu-section-list>li>div.beer-info'    
    mList = [selectForList(li, selRef) for li in pgSoup.select(mSel)]

    ## find moremenu button ##
    fetchMore, lmmCt = True, 1
    mmBtn_sel = [
        'a[data-href=":moremenu"][data-section-id]', 
        'a[data-href=":moremenusection"][data-menu-id]'
    ]
    mmBtn, msBtn = pgSoup.select_one(mmBtn_sel[0]), False
    if not mmBtn: 
        mmBtn, msBtn = pgSoup.select_one(mmBtn_sel[1]), True
        if not mmBtn: 
            fetchMore = False
            print(f"could not find '{', '.join(mmBtn_sel)}'")
    
    ## load more ##
    mSel = 'li>div.beer-info'   
    sectCt = len(pgSoup.select('.section-area .menu-section')) 
    sectId = mmBtn.get('data-section-id') if mmBtn else None
    menuId = mmBtn.get('data-menu-id') if mmBtn else None
    while fetchMore:
        lmmUrl = f'/venue/more_menu/{venuId}/{len(mList)}?section_id={sectId}'
        if msBtn: 
            lmmUrl = f'/venue/more_menu_section/{venuId}/{sectCt}'
            lmmUrl += f'?menu_id={menuId}'
        print(f'[{lmmCt}] loading more from {rootUrl+lmmUrl}', end='')
        lmReq = requests.get(f'{rootUrl}{lmmUrl}', headers={
            'accept': 'application/json', 
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'})
        try: 
            lmReq.raise_for_status() 
            jData = lmReq.json()
            fetchMore = jData['count']
            lmSoup = BeautifulSoup(jData['view'])
            if lmmUrl: sectCt += fetchMore
            print(f'\r[{lmmCt}] loaded {fetchMore} more from {rootUrl+lmmUrl}')
        except Exception as e: 
            return vRet(f'\n{type(e)} - {e}', mList)
        
        ## get more menu items from html string instide json response ##
        mList += [selectForList(li, selRef) for li in lmSoup.select(mSel)]
        lmmCt += 1
    
    ## some cleanup [and maybe add venue name,id,link] ##
    for mi, m in enumerate(mList):
        m['about'] = m['about'].replace(m['brewery'], '').strip(' \u2022')
        for k in ['link', 'brewery_link', 'log_src']:
            if str(m[k])[:1] == '/': mList[mi][k] = f'{rootUrl}{m[k]}'
        
        mDets = {'venueId': venuId, 'venue': vName} if includeVenue else {}
        for k, v in mList[mi].items(): 
            if k=='about' and v: v = v.strip('\u2022').strip().strip('\u2022')
            mDets[k] = v.strip() if isinstance(v, str) else v
        if includeVenue: mDets['venue_link'] = umLink
        mList[mi] = mDets
    
    return vRet(f'{len(mList)} menu items from {umLink}', mList)
```

You could call it for a single venue like

```py
menuList = scrape_untappd_menu('/v/southern-cross-kitchen/469603')
```

[image: svenop]

or, if you want to scrape menus from multiple venues:

```py
menuList = []
for vl in venueLinks: 
    menuList += scrape_untappd_menu(vl, includeVenue=True)
    print()
```

and you can also save the results as CSV (using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) below):

```py
pandas.DataFrame(menuList).to_csv('untappd.csv', index=False)
```